# Dispatch a store action from AngularFireAuth

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I've created a store with a Users State in the same way that they handle states in the **RxJS example app**: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

It works fine for register, login, logout... The reducers and effects do their jobs without exceptions.

The problem comes with the initial state (and the authstate stream from AngularFire.auth). I wanted to set the initial state from the **AngularFireAuth Subject**, like they do in the last example app: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md

In the main *app.component.ts*, I just **subscribe** to Af.auth in the constructor, in order to update the store if the user was already logged in, and **dispatch** the authState from my store:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

showSidenav$: Observable<boolean>;
currentUser$: Observable<User>;
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
          private router: Router,
          private Af: AngularFire,
          public dialog: MdDialog,
) {
this.showSidenav$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getShowSidenav);
this.currentUser$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getCurrentUser);
this.isLoggedIn$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getIsLoggedIn);
this.Af.auth.subscribe(authState =>
  this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUserStateAction(authState)));
}
```

But when I access to the app, it's displayed but I get the following error in the console:

```
reducer.js:22 TypeError: Illegal invocation
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102121:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at deepFreeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102118:33)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102124:7
at Array.forEach (native)
at deepFreeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102118:33)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102124:7
at Array.forEach (native).....
```

and this one under it:

```
client?ffdb:44 [WDS] Disconnected!
```

And If I try to log in, it shows this one:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__zone_symbol__xhrScheduled' of function 'function XMLHttpRequest() { [native code] }'
    at ZoneTask.scheduleTask [as scheduleFn] (zone.js:1969)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.662.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:384)
    at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:274)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.662.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:378)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.662.Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:209)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.662.Zone.scheduleMacroTask (zone.js:232)
    at zone.js:2014
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (eval at createNamedFn (zone.js:1476), <anonymous>:3:31)
    at F.send (auth.js:71)......
```

How could I set the initial state in my store from the AngularFireAuth? This would mean to send the AuthStates events from AngularFire.auth to my store whenever they happen.

I get the same error if I change the Af.auth.subscribe to this other way:

```
this.Af.auth.map(authState => new 
  user.UpdateUserStateAction(authState)).subscribe(store);
```

**EDIT**: I add the workflow:

User logs in with email, when clicks on the button it triggers *onSignInWithEmail(formValue)*:

```
  onSignInWithEmail(formValue) {
    this.store.dispatch(new user.LogInFromPasswordAction(formValue));
  }
```

An Effect receives the action, sets the user data in my Firebase Database, and triggers the action *LogInFromPasswordSuccessAction(finalUser)*:

```
  @Effect()
  logInFromPassword$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(user.ActionTypes.LOG_IN_FROM_PASSWORD)
    .flatMap((action) => Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>this.userService.loginWithEmail(action.payload))
    .flatMap((data) => Observable.of(this.userService.setUserData(data.auth))
    .map((finalUser) => new user.LogInFromPasswordSuccessAction(finalUser))));
```

Finally the reducer receives that action and returns the new State:

```
case user.ActionTypes.LOG_IN_FROM_PASSWORD_SUCCESS: {
  const commingUser = action.payload;
  return {
    data: commingUser,
    isLoggedIn: true
  };
}
```

What I keep in my store is the User data I selected, with a User model I created.

The reason of doing it like this is to have all the data and streams in the same central store, so I can access to anything from "fromRoot" and update from the same place.

Comment: Can you please share _reducer.js:22_ - apparently that is where the error occurs, correct?

Comment: Sorry the reducer.js is from the store-devtools (I improved the details in the question). Reducers and effects works fine without the line that subscribes to Af.auth and dispatches the action. Is that line that causes the problem, I guess because is not possible to dispatch an action from a subscription?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the auth-object from angular-firebase has an issue with the deepFreeze - probably the easiest way to debug this is to set breakpoints and step through the code.

But in general it is not a good practice to take non-primitive objects (in your case the `firebase.User`, name as `authState`) and save them directly to your store. Instead you should only save the relevant and required information to your store (probably the UserName?). Also to recreate the authentication you would need the credentials anyway, so having the whole object is not of much help here.

Additionally: Since `this.Af.auth` is already an observable, why would you need to save the contents to your store, it is already accesible in a stream-like manner.

Comment: I added the workflow. I just keep the User data I need in the store, and I want to update that state whenever an event is sent from Af.auth. I just wanted to not have to import Af.auth whenever I need the user data, and only to import the fromRoot.

Comment: Okay, but then you should copy the contents of that user-object, because freezing an object provided by some foreign module is never a good idea, there is a very good chance that this will cause some issues in that external module.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. I suppose you mean using Object.assign()? Also, do you know how could I update the state of the user in fromRoot by receiving the data from Af.auth?

Comment: for example by copying the data, but not taking the object as a reference - however if `Object.assign` is sufficient or if you have to do a _deep copy_ i cannot tell because I don't have the complete interface a `firebase.User`-class in my head currently ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Finally I'm handling the user state from and injectable service with observables, rather than from the store. Whenever I need the current state of the user I inject the service. Too much trouble with the approach I was trying...